# Why is my data squashed in the middle of the chart?

Tags: python, seaborn

Why is my data squashed in the middle like this with massive gaps on the edges? I tried to truncate=true but that didnt work.

[image: The chart]

The code:

```
import yfinance as yf  
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns 
import datetime as date
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
import datetime

Ins_Name = "EURUSD=X"
#Ins_Name = "AAPL"
df = yf.download(Ins_Name,'2019-05-01','2020-01-03')

df.reset_index(inplace=True)
df['date_ordinal'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date']).apply(lambda date: date.toordinal())

sns.set()
#plt.figure(figsize=(26, 10))
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15,7))
#ax = sns.lmplot('date_ordinal', 'Close', data=df, fit_reg=True, aspect=2, ) #Scatter PLot
ax = sns.regplot(data=df,x='date_ordinal',y=df.Close,truncate=True,scatter_kws={"color": "red"}, line_kws={"color": "black"}, marker='x') #scatterplot

ax.set_xlabel('Interval', fontsize=25)
ax.set_ylabel('Price', fontsize=25)
ax.set_title('Mean reversion of ' + Ins_Name + ' Close Prices',fontsize= 45,color='black')
new_labels = [datetime.date.fromordinal(int(item)) for item in ax.get_xticks()]
ax.set_xticklabels(new_labels)
```

Comment: Yeah that worked. Thank you JohanC. You should redo that as an answer so that I can mark it as one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try explicitly setting the xlim. Pandas dataframes and matplotlib seem to behave differently when time is used for the axes.

For example:

`ax.set_xlim([datetime.date(2019, 5, 1), datetime.date(2020, 1, 3)])`